# How to switch from one storyboard to another storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, uistoryboard

Team,

I have two storyboard.
One For authentication
And another for My application Dashboard.

For Authentication Storyboard The initialisation screen is loginScreen.
After login successfully i am loading Dashboard Storyboard.
For dashboard storyboard the initial screen is MainViewController.

Here I am implemented logout from in DashboardStoryboard. So now i want to switch back to my Authentication Storyboard.

Here its going back to loginScreen.
But I thing its not proper way for implementing.
It will be more helpful is there a way I can do better?

```
-(void)logout{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Authentication" bundle: nil];
    LoginViewScreenController *loginViewScreenController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewScreenController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: loginViewScreenController animated:NO];
}
```

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using two storyboards and not just separate view controllers?

Comment: @Andriko13  I am using two Storyboard.

Comment: you must look into storyboard references https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226

Comment: you dont need to use more then one storyboard if you are working only for iPhone, you can navigate your app after login or logout or in any case to the another VC.

Comment: @kiran check my ans  and lets know your feedback.

Comment: @vaibhav we can use multiple storyboard if iPhone app or universal app.   I do not understand why only single storyboard for iPhone app.

Comment: @kiran its completely up to you but here i have suggested if you have situation like login or logout so you can handle this by having single storyboard.

Comment: @vaibhav my question is good practice or bad one.  Because there is way to implement multiple storyboard for iPhone application

Comment: okay, both have diff implementation way now you can try and optimize the app performance accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It's Very easy using `segue` and `Storyboard Reference`. Please follwo steps and screenshots.

**Step-1)**

- Drag and drop `Storyboard Reference` from Object Library in First(Main) Story board.

[image]

**Step-2)**

- Add segue from your source ViewController to `Storyboard reference.`

**Step-3)**

- Select another(second) storyboard.
- Reference ID: StoryboardID of your destinationViewControler(second View Controller) which is available in `Second.Storyboard`

  [image]

[image]

---

```
-(void)logout
{
    UIViewController *aVCObj = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window.rootViewController;
    if ([aVCObj isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *aNavController = (UINavigationController *)aVCObj;
        [aNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick to do this by setting up a key `true` using `NsuserDefaults` when user logged in otherwise `false` and navigate your application when starts *accordingly* using `presentViewController` method without animation so the user will not get any option to go back previous vc.

Have a look below code illustrating above sentence:

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isloggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

}else{        // when logout
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"logoutView"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

If you need to apply some effects when vc appear just ad these two lines before `presentViewController` method see:

```
[vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCustom];
[vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
```

**Note:** set the key **false** when user logout.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let homeVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = homeVC
```